# SSIS Set SQL agent job for child package in 32 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012, 32-bit, sql-agent-job

I have a parent package "Master.dtsx" containing 3 child packages. Each is executed with "Execute package task".

Master package is set as "32-bit runtime" in SQL Agent Job. However, child packages are not running in 32bit mode. Is there any approach to set child package "32-bit runtime" from Master, or any other work around?

P.S.

1) I'm SURE child pkgs are not in 32 bit because I tried to execute each one separately from "SSISDB" with "32-bit" checked and succeeded. But when executed from Master they failed.

2) I tried with "execute process task" for child packages in Master as this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b58d55c4-0d3b-4f27-8aea-be7cf0ecdd76/execute-child-package-in-32-bit-within-a-64-bit-master-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices) shows, but it always fails...  Also, "Run64BitRuntime" in "Debug Options" for that project is set as "False"  in visual studio

3) To set each child package as a single step in SQL agent job and make them to be "32-bit runtime" from there could be the last choice... please provide something more than that, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why not run each package as its own step?  Do you have a lot of variables/parameters to wire together?  You might have to bite the bullet...

Answer (score 0):

Using execute process task instead of execute package task is the way to do it. The link you've seems to be accurate; but make sure you're entering package path in double quotes. So in the arguments field, enter package path as `/file "Your full path.dtsx"`

Hope this helps!